# centralWidget size seems erroneous?

Tags: python, qt5, pyqt5

I am trying to figure out a way to get a simple QMainWindow to show an empty QWidget and report the real screen size used to the command line. What works (modified ZetCode PyQt5 tutorial stuff):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QAction, QApplication, QWidget, QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Example(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):               

        self.setCentralWidget(QWidget(self))

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('exit24.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.statusBar()

        #menubar = self.menuBar()
        #fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        #fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        #toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        #toolbar.addAction(exitAction)

        self.setGeometry(700, 100, 300, 700)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main window')    
        self.show()

        #TL -> topLeft
        TL = QPoint(self.centralWidget().geometry().x(), self.centralWidget().geometry().y())
        print("TL_Relative",TL)
        print("TL_Absolute:",self.mapToGlobal(TL))

        #BR -> bottomRight
        BR = QPoint(self.centralWidget().geometry().width(), self.centralWidget().geometry().height())
        print("BR_Relative",BR)
        print("BR_Absolute:",self.mapToGlobal(BR))


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Results are:

```
TL_Relative PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint()
TL_Absolute: PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(700, 100)
BR_Relative PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(300, 678)
BR_Absolute: PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(1000, 778)
```

However, when I uncomment all the commented out initUI entries, I get:

```
TL_Relative PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(0, 65)
TL_Absolute: PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(700, 165)
BR_Relative PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(300, 613)
BR_Absolute: PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(1000, 713)
```

The top values are okay, but `BR_Relative` no sense to me. Adding things at the top of the screen removes height from the bottom?

I also tried a lot of other ways. `geometry()`, `rect()` with its `topLeft()` and `bottomRight()`... they all show (nearly) the same result.

Where am I wrong?

In case its important: I am running a Raspbian powered RPi2 with Python 3.4/PyQT5. Reason for this script is to have a framework that can hold OMXplayer "inside" handing over the gained coordinates to its `--win`-parameter when launching OMXplayer. After launching, OMXplayer is supposed to overlay the empty centralWidget. But as soon as I add the menu or the toolbar, the OMXplayer window doesn't fit any more. Only statusBar works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A picture is worth a thousand words. From the [QMainWindow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework) docs:

[image: Qt Main Window Framework]

So, since the window geometry remains the same, the menubar and toolbar must take space away from the central-widget. The original height of the central widget was `678`; subtract `65` and you get `613`.

To get the correct values, try:

```
    geometry = self.centralWidget().geometry()
    print("TL_Relative", geometry.topLeft())
    print("TL_Absolute:", self.mapToGlobal(geometry.topLeft()))

    print("BR_Relative", geometry.bottomRight())
    print("BR_Absolute:", self.mapToGlobal(geometry.bottomRight()))
```

Comment: Thank you! You made me find my thinking error. I was assuming height() shows the bottom right coordinates of the Central Window as stated in a graphic for a QWidget description (I don't find the link right now). So... I do have to copy the Central Window TL position my wrong named BR "position" to get the real one. (Is there a better/easier way?)

Comment: @Bigfoot29. It looks like you may have overlooked one possibility - see my updated answer.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thing that also works:
        X1=self.centralWidget().geometry().x() \n
        Y1= self.centralWidget().geometry().y() \n
        X2 = X1 + self.centralWidget().geometry().width() \n
        Y2 = Y1 + self.centralWidget().geometry().height() \n
        TL = QPoint(X1, Y1) \n
        BR = QPoint(X2, Y2) \n
(This would be the "direct" solution to my code approach. But yours is better and only giving the "inline" space. And sorry for the bad coding here. No line break in the comments. :/ )